# What is partial least squares (PLS) regression and how is it different from OLS?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, partial-least-squares

Assume we have a simple linear regression model expressed as $$y= X \beta + \epsilon,$$ where $y$ is a vector of size $n \times 1$, $X$ is a matrix of size $ n \times p$, $\beta$ is the regression coefficients vector of size $p\times 1$, and $\epsilon$ is a noise vector of size $n\times1$.

We all know that the Ordinary Least Squares (OLS) estimator of $\beta$ cannot be used when $p\gg n$. That is why there are a lot of alternative methods were proposed. One of these methods is the Partial Least Squares (PLS) estimator. I read some resources which explain the PLS, but unfortunately I didn't understand well the concept and the main difference between OLS and PLS.

**So can someone kindly explain me in detail how PLS works?**

Furthermore, can someone write me the Matlab code of how to estimate the $\beta$ vector using PLS?

Comment: Maybe section 3.5.2 of this will help : http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf

Comment: Regarding Matlab, note that there is [`plsregress()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/plsregress.html).

Comment: This CV thread on PLS is related http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179733/theory-behind-partial-least-squares-regression