# A mathematical description of Partial Least Squares (PLS)?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, partial-least-squares, regularization

I have read many articles about PLS, but I could not understand the mathematical description yet. I know that it is quite similar to principal component regression (PCR), except that it takes into account the direction of the response variable.

Could you please provide for me a simple mathematical explanation e.g the formula and coefficient estimates form?

Comment: We already have a thread on [Theory behind partial least squares regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/179733/22228). I think this question largely duplicates that one. If that doesn't adequately answer your question, perhaps you can edit this to make clear what is distinctive about your request?