# Are there constraints on the ratio of dependent variables to independent variables for PLS regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, partial-least-squares

I will begin with a disclaimer that while I understand the general underlying principles behind PLS, my linear algebra background is rather limited.
I have trouble with the details of constraints on the various elements of the method, which is the reason I'm asking this.
I've taken a look at a number of papers reviewing the uses of PLS and answers on this site explaining PLS theory (such as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179767/208698)), none addressing my issue

Say we are in the scenario of multi-response PLS (or PLS2).
We have $Y$ the dependent values matrix $n$ observations by $p$ variables, $X$ the independent values matrix $n$ by $q$.

I'm aware that PLS deals rather well in instances with $n << p$, provided that $n$ itself isn't too small. 
Also, that if $q >> p$, we are likely to overfit.

My question however, lies more in whether there are issues if $q << p$.

As far as I'm concerned, PLS regression (PLSR) is very powerful in a multi-response scenario where there are highly correlated groups of variables within $Y$ (such as gene expression data for instance).